# CSS - Align absolute element based on direction

Tags: css, sass

I have a `position: absolute;` element (the arrow in the example), and i want to Align him based on his parent direction.

For example:
If the parent (the box) has `direction: ltr;` the element will aligned to the left 30 pixels away. like this:

[image]

But if the parent (the box) has `direction: rtl;` the element will aligned to the right 30 pixels away. like this:

[image]

I'm actually looking for something similar to `start` and `end` in flex box.

Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found this solution:

Set to the child this:

```
inset-inline-start: 30px
```